# Geopandas: how to convert the column geometry to string?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have a geopandas dataframe

```
    geometry                                           idx
0   POLYGON ((-74.25559 40.91553, -74.24559 40.915...   0
1   POLYGON ((-74.25559 40.90553, -74.24559 40.905...   1
2   POLYGON ((-74.25559 40.89553, -74.24559 40.895...   2
3   POLYGON ((-74.25559 40.88553, -74.24559 40.885...   3
4   POLYGON ((-74.25559 40.87553, -74.24559 40.875...   4
```

where

```
gridDF['geometry'][0]
 <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon at 0x7fa4cc6ccc50>
```

I would like to convert the entries in the column `geometry` as a string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use apply if you want to do all rows at once.

```
from shapely import wkt
gridDF['str_geom'] = gridDF.geometry.apply(lambda x: wkt.dumps(x))
```

Comment: can also write this as 
```gridDF['str_geom'] = gridDF['geometry'].apply(wkt.dumps)
```

`wkt.dumps` is already a single function, so not required to write it inside a lambda

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this function: [shapely.wkt.dumps](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.wkt.dumps)

Example:

```
from shapely import wkt
wkt_string = wkt.dumps(gridDF['geometry'][0])
print(wkt_string)
```

The `wkt_string` should be the geometry as string in wkt format.